# How to fix data flow when you can't open it?

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Scenario :**

- I'm happily working on my custom Data flow like I do every day.
- I click on "save" like I always do 100 times a day.
- I wait for the popup confirming the save.
- I reload the page -- because of reasons
- **PROBLEM : the data flow can no longer be displayed. It is now corrupt.**

  - When I click on its name in the tree structure in the left panel, nothing happens. Other data flowas can be open normally.
  - When I double click on the Data flow in an "Execute data flow" activity (that I just happened to have lying around), same thing : the data flow does not open.

**Probable cause :**

Somehow one of the expressions in the flow confuses the DSL parser.
I can see this in the browser's debug console :

[image]

> line 56:40 extraneous input '"' expecting {')', ','}

It made me have a closer look at the DSL file (obtained through context menu "Download support files") :

[image]

I opened the DSL file in VSCode and it clearly shows a broken syntax (it highlighted this extra curly bracket **{** in red straight away ) :

[image]

**For reference,** this is the json of the dataflow (below). You can see that unwanted **{** there too :

```
{
    "name": "ReplyDF",
    "properties": {
        "folder": {
            "name": "V.1"
        },
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlOldMessaging",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "Message"
                },
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlOldMessaging",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "User"
                },
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlOldMessaging",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "ReadEntry"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "RawFromAdf_NewMessaging",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "Reply"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "ids"
                },
                {
                    "name": "joinUser"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ConvertMentionsInText"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AddContext"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CreateContextColumn"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     MessageId as integer,",
                "     ThreadId as string,",
                "     AssignmentId as string",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as integer,",
                "          Timestamp as string,",
                "          Text as string,",
                "          ConversationId as integer,",
                "          UserId as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     format: 'query',",
                "     store: 'sqlserver',",
                "     query: (replace('SELECT * FROM dbo.Message where id={id}','{id}', toString($MessageId))),",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED') ~> Message",
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as string,",
                "          OrganizationId as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     format: 'query',",
                "     store: 'sqlserver',",
                "     query: (replace('select distinct u.Id, u.OrganizationId from dbo.Message m join [dbo].[User] u on u.Id = m.UserId WHERE m.id = {Id}', '{Id}', toString($MessageId))),",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED') ~> User",
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as integer,",
                "          Timestamp as string,",
                "          MessageId as integer,",
                "          UserId as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     format: 'query',",
                "     store: 'sqlserver',",
                "     query: (replace('SELECT * FROM dbo.ReadEntry WHERE MessageId = {Id}','{Id}',toString($MessageId))),",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED') ~> ReadEntry",
                "AddContext derive(parent = $ThreadId,",
                "          GuidId = uuid()) ~> ids",
                "ids, User join(UserId == User@Id,",
                "     joinType:'left',",
                "     matchType:'exact',",
                "     ignoreSpaces: false,",
                "     broadcast: 'auto')~> joinUser",
                "CreateContextColumn select(mapColumn(",
                "          timestampAsString = Timestamp,",
                "          text = newText,",
                "          userId = UserId,",
                "          parent,",
                "          id = GuidId,",
                "          organizationId = OrganizationId,",
                "          readByAsArray = readBy,",
                "          context = {\"assignment-{$AssignmentId}",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: false) ~> ConvertMentionsInText",
                "Message derive(Context = $AssignmentId) ~> AddContext",
                "ConvertMentionsInText derive(Context = \"assignment-{$AssignmentId}\") ~> CreateContextColumn",
                " sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:true,",
                "     format: 'document',",
                "     partitionKey: ['/parent'],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> Reply"
            ]
        }
    } }
```

Congrats to the ADF team for its pristine sanitation -- that allows UI-breaking custom values into the data!

**Troubleshooting**

- I tried reloading the page, even Ctrl+F5. still can't open the Dataflow
- I tried cloning the data flow. Same issue with the cloned one.

**My question :**

**How can I fix broken syntax in a data flow's files when I can't open the data flow?**
Frustratingly, you get to click on the "view the JSON code representation" button only *after* you open the data flow... You'd need to access that file *before* opening the data flow, in order to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up **editing the json file directly** in my **git** repository instead of relying on the ADF UI.

> To do so, you can edit files directly if you host them in github, or
> you can clone the repo locally and open it with your favorite editor,
> then commit and push the changes.

It took a bit of trial and error but since it was in git I could safely revert bad changes. No danger here!

The file is in `/ADF/dataflow/YOUR_FLOW.json`.

Of course I did not attempt to "fix" the whole flow like that. **The goal is only to change the broken field to a value that could be parsed.**

So, I arbitrarily changed the incriminating line from :

```
context = {\"assignment-{$AssignmentId}\"}",
```

to:

```
context = UserId,",
```

...I picked UserId at random just because I saw a few lines above in my dataflow that this column does exist and is accepted by parsing. Use whatever you feel like, and make sure not to break the trailing sequence of characters: double quotes followed by coma **",**

- **commit** the change
- **push** the change
- **reload** the ADF page (F5 in the browser),
- The dataflow could finally be opened.
- **IMPORTANT: Even if the flow still can't be loaded ,** at least if the syntax of the JSON file is sufficiently readable then you'll get an error in UI telling you that "one of the resources or references could not be parsed" (finally, a real error message!). If so, then :

  - close the error message
  - close the panel showing you the JSON of the pipeline (that's not where the problem is, obviously it's still int he underlying dataflow)
  - with the panel on the left, open directly the JSON of the Dataflow.
  - Sure, it can't be parsed. But now ADF lets you edit it!
  - Edit the JSON and save it there until it gets accepted.

**Success!**

Don't be afraid of breaking it again with a "bad" value in one of the expression fields (*"bad" as in "badly sanitízed, breaking the flow and the UI, and the ADF team should be ashamed*), because now you know how to fix it.

Comment: This is the only solution I'm aware of, great job getting it working again. You should be able to mark this as the answer.